# TextRange.Save 'rich text format' not supported

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a private assembly added to my SSRS 2005 report.  I can run the assembly successfully in a test platform but when I try to run the report it breaks. Opening a run-time debugger I break on this line:

```
textRange.Save(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

with the exception

```
'Rich Text Format' data format not supported
```

The assembly is built with framework 3.5

Comment: Did you create your own rendering extension? (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624(v=sql.90).aspx)

SSRS doesn't have built-in RTF redering.

Comment: SSRS 2005 does not render RTF.  This is the reason I'm using the TextRange class.  The final step in the code is to convert the stream to an image to use in SSRS2005.   I realize the best way would be to upgrade to SSRS 2008 where RTF can be rendered so my solution is designed to allow for an easy upgrade when I can switch to SSRS 2008 or newer.